# zf2 cant render partial navigation

Tags: zend-framework2, partials, zend-view, zend-navigation

I'm trying to do ` $partial = array(**DIR**.'/menu.phtml', 'default');

```
  echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial($partial);`
```

and im getting error `Fatal error: Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException: Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "/home/cawa/www/zf2/module/Nav/view/layout/menu.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file in /home/cawa/www/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/AbstractHelper.php on line 471`

what is the problem?

Comment: Apparently the file is non existant `/module/Nav/view/layout/menu.phtml`  THat's all the error gives you.

Comment: no the file is there, if theres no such file it gives another error

Comment: I'm not sure if the Resolver can handle absolute paths. Try setting it to 'layout/menu.phtml'. If this still won't work, something is wrong with your resolver. In this case, report back to us and we'll check your configuration. **NOTE** that I had a typo in my comment. It has to be "layout/menu.phtml" - not "view/layout/menu.phtml".

Comment: thanks it was about the path, with /layout/menu.phtml it works , can u give me a link fore some examples of partials menu?

Comment: These are the docs I use the most (except browsing the sources on my own): http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html Hope this helps.

Comment: so theres no difference between $this->partial and this->navigation->menu-setpartial ???

Comment: and how i can combine zend_nagigation and partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also note about naming of menus - if the "navigation" keyword doesn't exist then container in the partial was empty for me.

```
<?= $this->navigation()->menu('navigation')->setPartial(array('partials/menu.phtml', 'default'))->render() ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.zfforum.de/einsteigerfragen/4749-zend_navigation-aktiver-eintrag-im-partial.html